# Changing a 2D list into a dictionary. Graph related question

Tags: python, list, graph

```
[[5, 8, 10], [2, 6], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 5], [4, 6, 9], [1, 3, 9],
 [6], [7, 10], [0, 6, 8, 10], []]
```

this means 5,8,10 follows 0 and 2,6 follows 1, etc

but I would want it to be in a list and

```
{0: [9], 1: [2, 3, 6], 2: [1, 4], 3: [2, 6], 4: [5], 5: [0, 3, 4],
 6: [1, 5, 7, 9], 7: [8], 8: [0, 9], 9: [5, 6], 10: [0, 8, 9]}
```

so, this means 0 follows 9, 1 follows 2,3,6, etc

how should I code it to convert it into that? I thought of doing a for-loop but im not sure how I should do it.

Comment: Please add the for-loop, that didn't work to your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
lst = [[5, 8, 10], [2, 6], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 5], [4, 6, 9], [1, 3, 9], [6], [7, 10], [0, 6, 8, 10], []]

dct = {}
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for elem in lst[i]:
        dct.setdefault(elem,[]).append(i)
```

You'd need to sort it if you want the keys in order

Comment: I would want it to be ```{0: [9], 1: [2, 3, 6], 2: [1, 4], 3: [2, 6], 4: [5], 5: [0, 3, 4], 6: [1, 5, 7, 9], 7: [8], 8: [0, 9], 9: [5, 6], 10: [0, 8, 9]}``` This means 0 appears in lst[9], 1 appears in lst[2], lst[3], lst[6]

Comment: I edited my solution. You'll need to sort it if you want the keys in order.

Comment: its work. thank you. but may i ask what does the setdefault mean?

Comment: setdefault(key, default) returns the element from the key, if it exists, or the default value. I used it to create an array if it didn't exist before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this. It is a brute force method, but it works for me. With `enumerate` you can get the element of the list and its index `pos`.

```
lst = [[5,8,10],[2,6],[1,3],[1,5],[2,5],[4,6,9],[1,3,9],[6],[7,10],[0,6,8,10],[]]

dict_lst = {}

for pos,sublst in enumerate(lst):
    for num in sublst:
        if not num in dict_lst:
            dict_lst[num] = [pos]
        else:
            dict_lst[num].append(pos)

dict_lst = {key: dict_lst[key] for key in sorted(dict_lst.keys())}
```